# Adding an Index to AP database

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am a CS student and I cannot figure out why my statement for adding an index will not work. To be specific, I am supposed to write a script that adds an index to the AP database for the zip code field in the Vendors table. I have attempted to do so using this statement:

```
CREATE INDEX (index_name) ON (table_name) ((column_name))
```

Am I missing something and I’m just not seeing it?

Comment: the syntax is wrong. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html too many parenthesis

Comment: Also, for the next question always post the error message you are receiving. That helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name)
```

For example, to create index "i" on table "t" with column "c", you would do:

```
create index i on t (c)
```

Comment: I tried it again and I received a message with error code 1831 with 1 warning. What does that mean?

Comment: Please add the exact SQL statement to your question, including the exact error message.

Comment: Ah... that index name is already in use. Try using a different index name.

Comment: Tried again using CREATE INDEX index_zip_code ON vendors (vendor_zip_code); and received the 1061 duplicate key name “index_zip_code” message. I’m confused, I get these error codes no matter what index name I attempt to create

Comment: You cannot create two index with same name.
Check `SHOW CREATE TABLE vendors;` result and check if there is `index_zip_code` index already created.

    `CREATE TABLE people ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(20),
    lastname VARCHAR(20));

    CREATE INDEX people1 ON people(firstname);
    CREATE INDEX people2 ON people(firstname);
    CREATE INDEX people1 ON people(firstname); <-- this produce error`